# MS Timestamp parsing Python

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

Is there a built-in function in python I can use to parse MS timestamps ?
For example, this "\x3a\xcf\x84\x72\x66\x42\xcd\x01" correspond to this date & time:
06/04/2012, 15:26:43.901625

Comment: Where is the timestamp coming from? are you getting a FILETIME struct? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: It come from the network, specifically the BROWSER service.

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp (as [@mandel mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884946/ms-timestamp-parsing-python#comment14186989_10884946)) looks like [`FILETIME` -- a 64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/188768):

```
import struct
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def FILETIME_bytes_to_datetime(timestamp_bytes):
    quadword, = struct.unpack('<Q', timestamp_bytes)
    us = quadword // 10 - 11644473600000000
    return datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(microseconds=us)
```

Example:

```
>>> FILETIME_bytes_to_datetime(b"\x3a\xcf\x84\x72\x66\x42\xcd\x01")
datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 4, 15, 26, 43, 901625)
```

`'<Q'` (little-endian unsigned 64-bit integer) might not work on all platforms (due to alignment of FILETIME structure fields, endianness).

To parse the value on Windows, you could use `ctypes.wintypes.FILETIME` structure:

```
import ctypes
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

if os.name == 'nt':
    import ctypes.wintypes

    FILETIME = ctypes.wintypes.FILETIME
else: # fallback
    DWORD = ctypes.c_uint32

    class FILETIME(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [('dwLowDateTime', DWORD),
                    ('dwHighDateTime', DWORD)]

def FILETIME_bytes_to_datetime(timestamp_bytes):
    t = FILETIME.from_buffer_copy(timestamp_bytes)
    quadword = (t.dwHighDateTime << 32) + t.dwLowDateTime
    us = quadword // 10 - 11644473600000000
    return datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(microseconds=us)
```

It uses native byte order, alignment (you can override it if necessary).